# Effective permissions for a shared mklink to a non-shared folder and subfolders

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, network-share, symbolic-link

What are the effective permissions if you share a symlink but not the folder it points to? From what I can see, there are 3 sets of permissions:

1) the target folder permissions

2) the symlink folder permissions

3) the symlink shared permissions

How are these applied and in what order?

Specific example:

Normal folder:

```
c:\
  |-test
  |----subtest 
  |--------nothere
```

symlink:

```
mklink /d c:\myshare c:\test
```

Assigned permissions:

User1 has full access to c:\test

User2 has no access to c:\test

I share the symlink "myshare", with sharing permissions set to "everyone-full access".

So, now there is a \server\myshare . Ideally, I would like:
a) user1 to continue have full access to \server\myshare and all subfolders (this works)
b) user2 to access \server\myshare, see the listing for "subtest", but not being able to access it. (this doesn't work).

Comment: You answer yourself, users2 have no access to c:\test, you need to give him directory naviguation right atleast (no file read) for that folder

Answer (score 2):

Use this command to grant full access

cd %systemroot%
takeown /f csc /r /a /d y
icacls csc /grant Everyone:(F) /t /l /q
then reboot.

vssadmin List Shadows

This will show you a list of your shadow copies (the shadow of the CSC folder will not be locked). Look for and copy the highest numbered original address.
Secondly we make a link to the shadow copy:

mklink /D C:\LatestShadow \?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy417\

The rightmost part of that should be the original address you copied before
Next use robocopy to get all the files out of the cache

mkdir C:\CSC_copy
robocopy C:\LatestShadow\Windows\CSC C:\CSC_copy /E /zb /copyall

then took ownership of the files in the C:\CSC_Copy